# Best practice to manage child components in combination with *ngIf

Tags: angular

I am struggling a lot to get a nice way of managing the children of a `Component` when the children are not always created because of `*ngIf`.

HTML structure of component `RootComponent`:

```
<div id="root-div" *ngIf="dto">
    <div id="nested-div-1" *ngIf="something">
        <my-nested-component>
        </my-nested-component>
    </div>
    <div id="nested-div-2" *ngIf="somethingElse">
        <div #anotherChild>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button (onClick)="setSomethingElse()">Button</button>
</div>
```

The problem:

- `RootComponent` is rendered.
- `REST` call is made in the `ngAfterViewInit` to get the `dto`, directly the `something` boolean is setted

  ```
  @ViewChild() myNestedComponent : MyNestedComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      restService.get().then((result) => {
          this.dto = result;
          this.something = true;
      }
  }
  ```
- Angular will now render the `root-div`, `nested-div-1` and `my-nested-component`.
- You will get a `undefined` exception when you do the following:

  ```
  @ViewChild() myNestedComponent : MyNestedComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      restService.get().then((result) => {
          this.dto = result;
          this.something = true;

          this.myNestedComponent.theMethod();
      }
  }
  ```
- This makes perfect sense, because Angular did not update the view yet, so `myNestedComponent` is undefined

**Bad/Hacky solutions**

1. Using `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to force Angular to update the view
2. Wrap `this.myNestedComponent.theMethod()` in a `setTimeout`, which delayes the execution of that line till Angular has done his cycle.

**Better solutions**

1. Give `my-nested-component` an `@Output` event, so that `my-nested-component` can execute a method in `RootComponent` when he is done initializing (for example in `ngAfterViewInit` of the `my-nested-component`)

   ```
   <my-nested-component (afterInit)="nestedComponentInitialized()"></my-nested-component>

   nestedComponentInitialized() {
       this.myNestedComponentIsInitalized = true;

       this.myNestedComponent.theMethod(); // Works now!
   }
   ```

   The problem with this approach is that the RootComponent needs check the `this.myNestedComponentIsInitalized` when he wants to do something with myNestedComponent
2. You can avoid this initialisation methods when you use the setter of the `@ViewChild()`. But requires still some code for every `@ViewChild`

   ```
   myNestedComponent: MyNestedComponent;

   @ViewChild() set myNestedComponentSetter(myNestedComponent: MyNestedComponent) {
       this.myNestedComponentIsInitalized = true;
       this.myNestedComponent = myNestedComponent;
   }
   ```
3. Change `@ViewChild` into `@ViewChildren`, so that is it possible to listen for changes of that list, which means the component is initalized

   ```
   @ViewChildren() myNestedComponents : QueryList<MyNestedComponent>;

   ngAfterViewInit() {
       restService.get().then((result) => {
           this.dto = result;
           this.something = true;

           this.myNestedComponents.changes.subscribe(() => {
               this.myNestedComponentIsInitalized = true;
               this.myNestedComponents[0].theMethod();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   The problem with this approach is that you can only listen for changes on a list, which feels strange when you already know that there is only one `MyNestedComponent` in your `RootComponent`. The good thing about this is that you can subscribe on the event of initialisation.

These three 'better solutions' become a nightmare when you have for example 4 different nested components. Because this means that the `RootCompoment` needs 4 initialisation methods (or 4 `QueryList`'s) with 4 booleans for the states of the nested components. Managing all of this becomes very complicated.

4. Don't use `*ngIf`, but use `[hidden]` so that everything exists always. This sounds good, but this means that everything is always rendered, and that you sometimes still to check if something exists. Because this will not possible (because `dto.name` can raise an exception, because `dto` is not initialized by the `REST` call yet):

   ```
   <div id="root-div" [hidden]="dto">
       <div id="nested-div-1" [hidden]="something">
           <my-nested-component>
           </my-nested-component>
       </div>
       <div id="nested-div-2" [hidden]="!somethingElse">
           <div #anotherChild>
               <span>{{dto.name}}</span> <!-- EXCEPTION, dto is not there yet! -->
           </div>
       </div>
       <button (onClick)="setSomethingElse()">Button</button>
   </div>
   ```

**The elegant solution?**

I am looking for a solution that makes it possible to manage the states of components that are not always initalized because of `*ngIf` conditions.

I would like to do things like:

- Wait till REST request is finished and `my-nested-component` and `anotherChild` are initialized.
- Pass component reference of `anotherChild` to `my-nested-component` when `anotherChild` is initalized (so `dto` and `somethingElse` were true), and `my-nested-component` is also there (so `something` was also true)

## TLDR

What is the best pattern or approach to manage nested `Component`s when they are not always there because of *ngIf?

Comment: Why dont you use the @ViewChildren decorator ? It'll provide you a QueryList object that you can subscribe to be aware of your components availability ?

Comment: He discussed that in his post.

Comment: I would personally go with the hidden route given the reasons you don't want to use viewchildren. Somehow you were controlling if those were shown or not using the ngIf in the beginning. I don't think it should be a problem to do so using hidden instead.

Comment: My preference is to use routing instead of container/component when component A needs to appear sometimes and other times component B. That way you can route to component A or route to component B and you don't need any `*ngIf` logic in the template.

Comment: @DeborahK Do you know an article/tutorial where this is explained in detail?

Comment: For routing in general: https://angular.io/guide/router For a course on routing: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing/table-of-contents For a quick set of routing tips: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaIAHOSKHCQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution is to design your angular project with respect to the container/component approach.

This means you have containers (parents) which handle the data and children which just render based on the input values. All actions that cause updates to data should be emitted via output from children to its parent, the parent updates the data and via input the updated data are passed down to the children again.

So your data flow would be always like this: service->container->component.

This concept comes mostly from flux/redux pattern and react, but it provides a lot of advantages also in angular. The benefits are:

- seldom use of viewchild (always a problem with undefined)
- better use of ChangeDetection strategy (children can often use ChangeDetection.OnPush)
- It forces to really think about the application structure
- It result in more readable code and no overloaded components

For Rest requests it is also nice to use the async pipe in combination with ngIf, your child gets rendered when all data is available. Take a look here: https://toddmotto.com/angular-ngif-async-pipe

A good guide for the container/component structure can be found here: https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/the-react-plus-redux-container-pattern/

And also here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

I know it is huge topic and I cannot explain all its complexity within one post, but maybe it gives you some inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for this! I like the benefits a lot, so I will give it a try :)